# Target external HTML elements that loads into div from main file

Tags: jquery, html, image, external

I have a main.html that loads external HTML (which contains images) into a div(#external). **How can I target these images from the main file?** I need to bind a load function into them that checks if the image is done loading so I can animate it. If I bind the load function directly on the external HTML it works but not sure how I can do the same thing but from the main file.

jquery:

```
$(".iframe").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $mylink = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#external").load($mylink)});
});
```

html:

```
<a class="iframe" href="pages/page.html">Test</a>
```

Comment: Did you try in this way? `$("#external img").load(function(){ //code })`

Comment: I take it by `.iframe` that your loading them into an iframe ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. @Billy - No I just named it like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the call back function, we cant rely on event delegation in this context since load event wont bubble,

```
$(".iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $mylink = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#external").load($mylink , function() {
       $("#external img").load(function(){ 
          //code 
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work here's a live link http://www.lonewulf.eu/test/ - But what happens when I have more images in that #external div that are not part of the external html? Because I do have some.

Comment: @zefs Then just give some identity to the images which are coming from the external html. And frame the selector according to it.

Comment: I tried it ony my main file. This method has some issues though, for example .swf object files do not load even if I remove the "img" selector from #external.

Comment: Nvm, adding the swf files inside iframes fixed this.